# importing a text file in Access?

Tags: date, ms-access, time

I have a large text file containing 4 attributes, I want to import this file in Microsoft access 2013 , but when the data is imported it gives an error

> Type Conversion Failure

This error is occurring on Date Time field

The format of Date and Time is like that:

*2008-02-02 15:36:08*

**Here is the sample of the file:**

[Sample of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQUWF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you might have skipped explicitly defining the date format during the import procedure. 
During the import process you need to click on advanced. This menu should appear:
[image: screenshot from advanced menu]

you want to make sure that the highlighted fields match the date format in the text file.

EDIT: you will also want to make sure that the field is imported as Data Type `Date Time`

Comment: I have follow these steps...but date and time field is displaying ###### instead of date and time